# Why doesn't the click event respond?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am applying a click event when the user clicks on `anchor` tag. This is the jquery that i wrote.

```
$('li.horizontal-tab-button-1').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
alert("asdasd");
$('#edit-account').css('display','none');
});
```

for this html :

[image]

but it does not get called. What could be the reason for this ? Where am I making the mistake ?

Comment: are you doing this in a dom ready state?

Comment: please post your full javascript.

Comment: Seems ok to me : http://jsfiddle.net/3nm9qu3x/ Don't forget the `$` at the beginning. And don't forget to include `jquery.js` too

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `$` on the line

```
('li.horizontal-tab-button-1').click(function(event) {
```

.

Should be

```
$('li.horizontal-tab-button-1').click(function(event) {
```

.

Also , as @singe31 pointed out, do not forget to add the `jquery.js´ or the most preferred Google CDN link

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

.

Comment: I forgot the $ sign. It is there in my script

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your JQuery in a document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('li.horizontal-tab-button-1').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("asdasd");
        $('#edit-account').css('display','none');
    });
});
```

Remember to objectify your element with the dollar sign